# Implementing 'exclusive or' to return one record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, logical-operators

I'm attempting to create a stored procedure that implements an exclusive or to return a specific record from a table (BasisValues).

Here's the table:

```
Basis   Value
1       4.25
2       1.25
3       99.00
0       0.00
```

I've designed a stored procedure to return a BasisValue as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBasisValue
                    @Basis VARCHAR(2)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Value FROM BasisValues
    WHERE ( BASIS  = @Basis) OR 
        ((BASIS <> @Basis) AND (Basis = '0'))
END
```

As you can see above, I'm attempting to SELECT the Value field from the BasisValues table according to the following logic:
1. If the Basis is equal to the @Basis passed into the stored procedure, return that value.
2. If the Basis is not equal to the @Basis passed into the stored procedure, then return the value of Basis = 0.

However, given a 'Basis' that exists in the table, I end up getting two records.  For example, if I called GET_BASIS_VALUES with a @Basis of 2 I get:

```
Basis   Value
2   1.25
0   0.00
```

In other words, I always return the '0' record no matter what.  What am I missing in terms of my logic?

Comment: So if I provide the value @Basis = '4' in the samples you provided what should be the result?

Comment: @dotnetom A Basis of 4 should return 0.  Basically, any Basis that is not in the table should return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `order by` to select the prefered value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Value
FROM BasisValues
WHERE ( BASIS  = @Basis) OR 
      ((BASIS <> @Basis) AND (Basis = '0'))
ORDER BY (case when BASIS = @BASIS then 1 else 0 end) DESC;
```

This query (without the `top`) will return one or two values, based on what you describe in the question.  It will then order the results, so the the non-default is first.  By choosing the first row after the `order by`, you get a match first, and then the default if there is no match.

Comment: Is the case clause in the order by just to handle BASIS values < 0?

Comment: @Donal . . . That is what the `or` does.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetBasisValue
                    @Basis VARCHAR(2)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ISNULL((SELECT Value FROM BasisValues
    WHERE (BASIS  = @Basis)), '0.00')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer does not have to depend on the value of your default basis or how it compares to other available choices, you can get this with the following

```
SELECT Value FROM BasisValues
WHERE BASIS  = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM BasisValues WHERE @Basis = BASIS ) THEN @Basis ELSE 0 END
```

What this says is, if the basis you asked for exists, return the value for that record, if it doesn't, return the value for record 0